# Heroku push failing, perhaps timeout from rubygems

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, heroku, git-push, gemfile

I'm trying to push to heroku using

```
git push heroku master
```

It gets stuck when trying to access rubygems:

```
    -> Heroku receiving push 
-----> Removing .DS_Store files 
-----> Ruby/Rails app detected 
-----> Installing dependencies using Bundler version 1.1.rc.5 
Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs bin/ 
Fetching gem metadata from http://rubygems.org/....... 
/app/slug-compiler/lib/utils.rb:62:in `block (2 levels) in spawn': command='/app/slug-compiler/lib/../buildpacks/ruby/bin/compile /tmp/build_38k3w88w3yxzg /app/tmp/repo.git/.cache' exit_status=0 out='' event=timeout elapsed=596.7476198673248 (Utils::TimeoutError) 
from /app/slug-compiler/lib/utils.rb:48:in `loop' 
from /app/slug-compiler/lib/utils.rb:48:in `block in spawn' 
from /app/slug-compiler/lib/utils.rb:44:in `popen' 
from /app/slug-compiler/lib/utils.rb:44:in `spawn' 
from /app/slug-compiler/lib/buildpack.rb:35:in `block in compile' 
from /app/slug-compiler/lib/buildpack.rb:33:in `fork' 
from /app/slug-compiler/lib/buildpack.rb:33:in `compile' 
from /app/slug-compiler/lib/slug.rb:464:in `block in run_buildpack' 
from /app/slug-compiler/lib/utils.rb:117:in `log' 
from /app/slug-compiler/lib/slug.rb:702:in `log' 
from /app/slug-compiler/lib/slug.rb:463:in `run_buildpack' 
from /app/slug-compiler/lib/slug.rb:107:in `block (2 levels) in compile' 
from /app/slug-compiler/lib/utils.rb:98:in `block in timeout' 
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:58:in `timeout' 
from /app/slug-compiler/lib/utils.rb:98:in `rescue in timeout' 
from /app/slug-compiler/lib/utils.rb:93:in `timeout' 
from /app/slug-compiler/lib/slug.rb:96:in `block in compile' 
from /app/slug-compiler/lib/utils.rb:117:in `log' 
from /app/slug-compiler/lib/slug.rb:702:in `log' 
from /app/slug-compiler/lib/slug.rb:95:in `compile' 
from /app/slug-compiler/bin/slugc:85:in `block in <main>' 
from /app/slug-compiler/lib/slug.rb:472:in `block in lock' 
from /app/slug-compiler/lib/repo_lock.rb:44:in `call' 
from /app/slug-compiler/lib/repo_lock.rb:44:in `run' 
from /app/slug-compiler/lib/slug.rb:472:in `lock' 
from /app/slug-compiler/bin/slugc:66:in `<main>' 
! Heroku push rejected, failed to compile Ruby/rails app

To git@heroku.com:[app].git 
! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined) 
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:[app].git'
```

this is my gemfile

```
    source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails'


# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'sqlite3-ruby', :group => :development
gem 'gravatar_image_tag'
gem 'acts_as_follower', "~> 0.1.1"

group :development do
gem 'rspec-rails'
gem 'annotate' 
end

gem 'faker'
gem 'pg' 
gem 'jquery-rails'

gem 'thumbs_up'
gem 'kaminari'

group :test do
gem 'rspec'
gem 'webrat'
gem 'factory_girl_rails'

end

gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby
gem 'execjs', "~> 1.2.9"

gem 'activeadmin'
gem 'meta_search'
  gem 'sass-rails'
group :assets do

 gem 'coffee-rails'
  gem 'uglifier'
end

# Use unicorn as the web server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger (ruby-debug for Ruby 1.8.7+, ruby-debug19 for Ruby 1.9.2+)
# gem 'ruby-debug'
# gem 'ruby-debug19', :require => 'ruby-debug'

# Bundle the extra gems:
# gem 'bj'
# gem 'nokogiri'
# gem 'sqlite3-ruby', :require => 'sqlite3'
# gem 'aws-s3', :require => 'aws/s3'

# Bundle gems for the local environment. Make sure to
# put test-only gems in this group so their generators
# and rake tasks are available in development mode:
# group :development, :test do
#   gem 'webrat'
# end
```

This never happened before.
The change in the gemfile was that I added acts_as_follower. All gems are updated using bundle update
What can I do to fix this?

**Update**:
I also tested `heroku run bundle update` and it stalls as well...

**Update 2:**
I now get

```
>git push heroku master
Enter passphrase for key '/c/Users/Me/.ssh/id_rsa':
Counting objects: 214, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (182/182), done.
Read from remote host heroku.com: Connection reset by peer
fatal: sha1 file '<stdout>' write error: Invalid argument
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:[app].git'
```

Comment: If you're on the Cedar stack you don't need RubyRacer or ExecJS in your Gemfile - Heroku advise against it. See http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails31_heroku_cedar#troubleshooting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved.

Problems was with active admin and meta_search
see https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/issues/182

That was a waste of a few days.. heroku support helped me figure that out

Answer (score 1):

Is it still occuring now? It would seem that the problem isn't yours to fix but Heroku's.

Did you check https://status.heroku.com/ when the problem was occuring? There was a problem with Heroku tools yesterday which may explain the problem.

Comment: Thanks but as of 5 minutes ago, it still happens. I saw the heroku status, it happened after I saw that all systems go. Anyone else have heroku push problems?

Comment: it doesn't help you but I've just added the same Gem, bundled and pushed to Heroku (cedar) and it pushed to Heroku fine.

Comment: I wonder, does it matter that I did bundler pack and the gem are uploaded to heroku? (I also don't know how to not do it, bundler install seem to do it automatically)

Comment: you need to commit both Gemfile and Gemfile.lock to git and push them both to Heroku will them bundle them when it compiles your slug.

Answer (score 0):

remove the faker gem from gem file then try, it may work...